# Juju 2.0 on ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: juju

juju 2.0 not supported on ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?

I have added the repository juju/devel and then tried to install juju but its not able to recognize juju-core2
I have checked that there is recent update on the juju link: https://jujucharms.com/docs/devel/getting-started

It appears its supported for Ubuntu, 16.04LTS(Xenial) only? I want to install on 14.04 but it appears its no more allowed there. I have tried it earlier on ubuntu 14.04 and it worked fine for me. But now its unable to bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

The package in the PPA is called 'juju2', not 'juju-core2'.

Comment: I have added the devel repository Package: juju                            
State: not installed
Version: 1.24.7-0ubuntu1~14.04.1
Priority: extra
Section: universe/devel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <br/>                                                            <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 114 k
Depends: juju-core (>= 1.24.7-0ubuntu1~14.04.1) <br/> but it cannot find the juju2 package in it.

Comment: It's there alright. This is what I have:
`dpkg-query -W juju2`<br/>
juju2   2.0-beta3-0ubuntu1~14.04.2~juju1
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/juju-devel-trusty.list`
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/juju/devel/ubuntu trusty main<br/>
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/juju/devel/ubuntu trusty main

Boy, do I dislike the markup on askubuntu.